# C++ AMP in Visual Studio 2015: Compiler/runtime bug or buggy sample?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-amp

I would like to try out the following C++ AMP code sample from Microsoft's documentation:

(Second code sample on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265136.aspx, slightly adapted to turn it into a program):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <amp.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace concurrency;

const int size = 5;

void CppAmpMethod() {
    int aCPP[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int bCPP[] = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int sumCPP[size];

    // Create C++ AMP objects.
    array_view<const int, 1> a(size, aCPP);
    array_view<const int, 1> b(size, bCPP);
    array_view<int, 1> sum(size, sumCPP);
    sum.discard_data();

    parallel_for_each(
        // Define the compute domain, which is the set of threads that are created.
        sum.extent,
        // Define the code to run on each thread on the accelerator.
        [=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
    {
        sum[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];
    }
    );

    // Print the results. The expected output is "7, 9, 11, 13, 15".
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << sum[i] << "\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    CppAmpMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately when compiled (using Visual Studio 2015) and executed this causes a run-time exception on the first of the array_view constructions.

```
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvwgf2um.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown at 0x0F9CC933 (vcamp140d.dll) in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD.
```

I am wondering how such a simple code sample could fail so badly. Is it the sample code that is wrong or is it the compiler? It could of course also be something particular to my system, since after all using C++ AMP might involve low-level interaction with the graphics driver etc. which could trigger bugs there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same here with Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL. Runs under Release.

Comment: Fine on another machine with Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1.

Comment: 4 years past, nothing changed,  VS2019 on Win10.

Comment: Sad - even if drivers etc. are involved in the error phenomenon, it still means the AMP API basically useless for any client app usage, given that the simplest sample program from Microsoft fails on mainstream machines.

Comment: Well, 4 years passed so tried again in VS2019. Now it won't even compile (amp.h(2616): error C3861:  '_Access': identifier not found)! I.e. syntax errors in the amp.h header file itself. The error not resolved by reordering or including Windows.h first or anything like that. Apparently a fix is in the works (May '19): https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/200035/c-amp-does-not-compile-with-permissive.html. Wonder how many are using C++ AMP? And how much testing it receives? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should change the Debugger Type to **GPU Only**.

Please see the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is likely the key:

"since after all using C++ AMP might involve low-level interaction with the graphics driver etc. which could trigger bugs there."

The sample should work, but you're required to have correct drivers for DirectX11.

There might be a chance you could attempt debugging the build using the software emulator. If you're using Windows 8 or higher, try editing properties in the solution explorer, under debugging, and review the options available in the debugger type list. See if NOT using GPU Only helps try this out.

Comment: Hi, thanks - unfortunately I can't find an option concerning GPU only etc. in the solution explorer. The only thing I could find under debugging was the setting "Amp default accelerator" which can be set to either "WARP Software accelerator" (which it was already at) or  "Use C++ AMP runtime default". I tried changing it to the latter but the exact same error is still there. Besides it seems the original setting was already to use software (probably because the project is in debug mode).

Comment: Can anyone try the above sample on their system? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, debug build threw exception (release build did not), Solution that worked for me was, update (repair install) Visual studio, even if I had the last build 2015 update 3, and then install the newest graphic drivers. I don't know what was the main reason, but I think that graphic drivers...